# Meta question, can I ask this here?

Tags: discussion

Before to ask my question I wanted to make sure that it was the appropriate place to ask it !

I would like to find a new supplier for my company in a specific country, is it possible to ask this community to help me in my duty or is it inappropriate ?

Thanks for your kind feedback !

Comment: Wrong place sorry

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers, I wanted to be sure before posting !

Comment: There are no Stack Exchange sites that allow you to ask for "shopping" recommendations, like asking who/what is the "best" product/supplier for a given item.

Comment: That was not the idea but I understand what you mean.@DJClayworth

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to find a new supplier for my company in a specific country, is it possible to ask this community to help me in my duty or is it inappropriate ?

I'm afraid that this is not the place. By doing that we are basically "doing your job". In TWP we address questions that have a goal and that are not opinion-based ("choose this provider... no choose this other").

However, if you phrase it in a good way (see [Help Center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)) it may be on-topic and something we could help you with. If you phrased it more like *"What would be the general steps for finding a new provider in..."* or "*What would be a professional and polite way to ask this company if they are willing to be our provider*", etc...

So, basically we can't do your job for you (find the provider) as that would be off-topic here and in any SE site I believe. What we can help you with is to navigate with any uncertainty you may have regarding the professional way of carrying that process.